# jQuery Access Dynamically Created Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery, dynamic, radio-button

I have 3 radio buttons on my page.  They are loaded by calling a jQuery function which returns the html ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- 
 onSelectChange(4);
  -->
```

which call this function:

```
function onSelectChange(parm){

        $.post("func.php", {function_name : "song"},
            function(data){
                $("#list").html(data.song_html);
                }, "json");
}
```

html returned looks like this:

```
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="songs" VALUE="A">A
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="songs" VALUE="B">B
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="songs" VALUE="C">C
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="songs" VALUE="D">D
```

Now I want to know when 1 one of these radio buttons is clicked so I have the following function:

```
 $("input[name='songs']").change( function() {
 alert($(this).val());
```

It never fires though - I think it has something to do with dynamically adding the controls because when I try the above on a static html page it fires as expected.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) when adding controls dynamically, like this:

```
$("input[name='songs']").live("change", function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

This works differently, rather than finding elements and binding a `change` handler to them, it binds a handler on `document` which listens for the `change` event to bubble up...and this happens the same way, no matter when the element was added.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name=songs]").change( function() {
 alert($(this).val());
}
```

no apostrophe after name=

Comment: You can enclose the name in quotes or not, both are valid...if there are any special characters it's required to use quotes.